# Hyper-V host - PFN_LIST_CORRUPT

Tags: hyper-v, bsod

I just built a new Hyper-V host machine. I installed Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter, then installed the Hyper-V role.

Now, while trying to install a guest OS (2008 R2) the guest will first bomb out with a disk corrupt error (at aprox. 65% expanding files), then shortly after (30-90 sec.) the host will BSOD with a "PFN_LIST_CORRUPT" error.

I've run the Windows Memory Diagnostic, and updated all drivers. There aren't any BIOS updates available.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It ended up being defective RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue to this (though; not a PFN under hyper-v) that was caused by a southgate that would send currupt bits when the chipset overheated.  Are you running this on a quality server, or a cheap whitebox.  Try running a memory test while doing heavy IO to try and heat up the board.

Comment: The processor and case temps are <40C, and the chipset heatsinks are cool to the touch, so I doubt that's the issues. I will test it like you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

With that ruled out, under those conditions, you should also check for voltage drop on each rail. (3.3,5,12...)

Low voltage conditions will affect memory consistency. Worst case scenario, run all drives and accessories from a second power supply and bridge the green wires. If you make it further, purchase a power supply with a 30-40% better wattage rating (minimum).

Comment: Thanks for the post, but that issue was corrected 3 years ago. The PSU tested good at the time, and was already substantially overpowered. It ended up being a motherboard/RAM compatibility issue due to the RAM being higher voltage "performance" version.